# Using Defs in SVG

Tags: html, svg

Im missing something here. A simple example using a `svg` element. 
I am defining the `defs` (reusable definition) and using within the element with `id` 'cry16CyclamenOpal_0.c15'.

[JSFiddle](https://jsbin.com/kogatin/edit?html,output)

Code:

```
<svg width="1366" height="612" id="_svg" class="svg" viewBox="-78.48 43.82 752.30 337.05" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <g id="def_CyclamenOpal">
            <path d="M0,22c0,12.2,9.9,22,22,22s22-9.8,22-22S34.2,0,22,0S0,9.9,0,22" fill="#795482"></path>
            <path d="M4.9,22h34.2l-1.3-6.5l-3.4-5.6L28.6,6H15.5l-5.3,3.8l-3.9,5.7L4.9,22z" fill="#DD9FBB"></path>
            <path d="M39.1,22H4.9l1.3,6.5l3.4,5.6l5.9,4h13.1l5.2-3.8l3.9-5.8L39.1,22z" fill="#552860"></path>
            <path d="M4.9,22l1.3,6.5l7.5-3.1l4.8,5l-2.9,7.7l6.1,1.3l7-1.3l-3.1-7.6l4.8-5l7.4,3l1.3-6.5l-1.3-6.5l-7.3,3.1l0,0l-4.8-4.9L28.6,6l-6.2-1.3L15.5,6l3,7.6l-4.9,4.9l-7.4-3L4.9,22z" fill="#D84C5D"></path>
            <path d="M18.5,30.7l-5.1-5.1v-7l5.1-5h7.1l5,5v7l-5,5.1H18.5L18.5,30.7z" fill="#A568AF"></path>
        </g>
    </defs>

    <g class="elementParent">
        <g id="cry16CyclamenOpal_0.c15" class="ele" data-action="ele" transform="matrix(0.27,0,0,0.27,339.422,124.718)">
            <circle class="outer" cx="22" cy="22" r="22" fill="url(#defs_CyclamenOpal)"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

My question is why is the defs not usable on screen? Why is the pattern not visible on the element on screen? Please see the jsfiddle.

Comment: apologies @RobertLongson, amended the question.

Comment: `id="def_CyclamenOpal"` and `#defs_CyclamenOpal` don't match anyway.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes, amended, however, still doesn't work.

Comment: you need to point your fill to a pattern, not a g

Comment: @Kayote - If you want to sprinkle your nice oval predictably within your app maybe you should build it with its center at (0,0). Therefore you could translate and scale it (if needed) as a use, via symbol defs. This, rather than attempting a pattern.

Comment: @RobertLongson that did it. Thanks Robert!

Comment: @FrancisHemsher Im not sure I follow. However, I do account for the centre of the shape when its moved, if that is what you meant.

Comment: @Kayote It's just so much easier to place/scale elements, such as your opal, if their center is at (0,0).

Comment: @FrancisHemsher A question that occured to me, considering I am using matrices, is there a way to define `transform-origin`. Thinking about your suggestion, it does make a lot of sense, however, from my understanding, you seem to be referring to css prop `transform-origin`, correct?

Comment: @Kayote Actually, I was referring to the transform attribute for the use element, including using matrix transform values. Then, since the origin is (0,0) you do not have to address that need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Note:*
>   I misread the question at first and posted an "off-the-target" answer.
>   I removed this part as it was not helpful to the OP's question.

Here is a (slightly modified) solution using the `<pattern>` tag to define a fill-pattern:

```html
<svg width="1366" height="612" id="_svg" class="svg" viewBox="-78.48 43.82 752.30 337.05" 
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="opal" x="0" y="0" width="45" height="45" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path d="M0,22c0,12.2,9.9,22,22,22s22-9.8,22-22S34.2,0,22,0S0,9.9,0,22" fill="#795482"></path>
            <path d="M4.9,22h34.2l-1.3-6.5l-3.4-5.6L28.6,6H15.5l-5.3,3.8l-3.9,5.7L4.9,22z" fill="#DD9FBB"></path>
            <path d="M39.1,22H4.9l1.3,6.5l3.4,5.6l5.9,4h13.1l5.2-3.8l3.9-5.8L39.1,22z" fill="#552860"></path>
            <path d="M4.9,22l1.3,6.5l7.5-3.1l4.8,5l-2.9,7.7l6.1,1.3l7-1.3l-3.1-7.6l4.8-5l7.4,3l1.3-6.5l-1.3-6.5l-7.3,3.1l0,0l-4.8-4.9L28.6,6l-6.2-1.3L15.5,6l3,7.6l-4.9,4.9l-7.4-3L4.9,22z" fill="#D84C5D"></path>
            <path d="M18.5,30.7l-5.1-5.1v-7l5.1-5h7.1l5,5v7l-5,5.1H18.5L18.5,30.7z" fill="#A568AF"></path>
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <g class="elementParent">
        <circle class="outer" cx="55" cy="155" r="100" fill="url(#opal)"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `<use>` *can* reference `<g>` actually - I `<use>` it all the time :D

Comment: @Niet the dark Absol: Yes, you are right, you can reference it with `<use>`. Unfortunately I misunderstood the question in the first place ;-)

Comment: @Robert: yeah, I will clean it up. I just left the first part, so the first two comments here did not loose their meaning.